# Chekout Page Redirect to checkout/noroute/

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout

I installed one page checkout in magneto 2.3.2 When i try to go in onepage checkout it give me 404 Not Found.

You can check this link what i actually face.

https://www.screencast.com/t/Osd2FSFcm

Comment: Did you get soluction?

Comment: any solution for this??